# Recursive issues

Tags: javascript, recursion, dom-events

When I have two text fields which listen to **change event** from one to another, it causes me an error saying **too much recursion**. Anyone has good solution?

Comment: Could you show an example using http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: How are you linking the two text boxes? Typically, js-based changes to a textbox don't trigger events.

Comment: Setting the value of a text field via `element.value` doesn't trigger the change event, which I thought was maybe how you were getting recursion. So can we see some code on how you have these listeners setup?

Comment: I connect to the two fields to on event change. For example, when I change the value in field 1, field 2 triggers the event change, vice versus.

Answer (score 1):

well you can hold a flag that holds the identity of the true event dispatcher. and break the event triggering if it matches.

Comment: i.e. pass/bind `{source: this}` as a data argument, and check `if (this === options.source) {}`

Answer (score 0):

You added an **onchange** event listener on both text fields; problem is, changing one text will trigger a change one the other field, which would trigger the **onchange** result for the first one, etc., resulting in an infinite loop.